# How to display product gallery image in the background of single product page of Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to have the first product gallery image on the background of the single product page (Woocommerce).

I know how do it with CSS to set background-img URL but im not a php developer, so its to hard for me to fix it.

Comment: In function php i did this but it nots working.    function child_filter_header_image( $default_thumbnail ) {
    if ( function_exists('is_product') && is_product() ) {
        $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
        if ( ! empty( $thumb ) ) {
            return $thumb;
        }
    }

    return $default_thumbnail;
}

add_filter( 'background_image_filter', 'child_filter_header_image' );

Answer (score 0):

Untested! However, you could try this:

```
<body style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), 'large' ); ?>');">
```

If you have thumbnail image theme supports, `large` should be available. If not, add `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );` to your functions.php file first.